# Get max value from enum using generics

Tags: c#, enums

How can I get the max int value from an enum using generics?

I have tried the following however it displays the following compilation error:

> Cannot implicitly convert T to int

```
    int maxValue = GetMaxValue<SomeEnum>(typeof(SomeEnum)); //expecting 2

    private static int GetMaxValue<T>(Type enumType)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<T>().Max();
    }

    public enum SomeEnum
    {
        ValueOne = 1,
        Value = 2
    }
```

Comment: Enum can only be defined as int, why should you use generics and try to cast them?

Comment: @ALFA Actually, an enum can also be defined as byte, short, or long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of C# **7.3** or later version, you can implement **Sweeper's** idea in a bit different way (with a help of `where T : Enum` constraint):

```
public static T GetMaxValue<T>() where T : Enum {
  return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Max();
}

...

SomeEnum max = GetMaxValue<SomeEnum>();
```

Please, note, that the result is `enum` itself and that's why we don't have any problems with enum underlying type (`byte`, `short` `int`, `long`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast to `int`, not `T`. And you don't actually need the `Type` parameter (unless you don't know the type at compile time), since you can just do `typeof(T)`:

```
private static int GetMaxValue<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>().Max();
}

// usage:
GetMaxValue<SomeEnum>() // 2
```

If your enums have `long` or some other type as the underlying type, you can specify another type parameter to cast them to:

```
private static U GetMaxValue<T, U>() where U : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<U>().Max();
}

// usage:
GetMaxValue<SomeLongEnum, long>()
```

Comment: This won't work if your enum is defined as `long` (or `byte` or `short`). Better use `Convert.ToInt32` to cover those cases (though it obviously doesn't cover the overflow case with `long`, but there's no way to cover it with that signature)

Comment: I think you can have a `long` enum just by casting it (`int` is default), so when you cast back to `int` it shouldn't create any problems, right?

Comment: @ALFA It will if the value is bigger than `int.MaxValue`

Comment: @KevinGosse My thought is that you cannot have a value bigger than `int.MaxValue` if in order to have a `long` enum first you have to cast from an `int` to `long` type.

Comment: *An enumeration is a set of named constants whose underlying type is any integral type*, [Enum Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum).

Comment: @ALFA I'm not sure why you assume you need to cast from int to long. `public enum SomeEnum : long { ValueOne = 30000000000 }` is valid

Comment: @KevinGosse you're right, I was sure the only way to have a long enum was to cast it from an int enum. Got it now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert.ToInt32`

```
 return Convert.ToInt32(Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<T>().Max());
```

---

But usually I do this, more faster than calling GetValues

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    ValueOne = 1,
    Value = 2,
    END
}

return (int)(SomeEnum.END - 1);
```